# how to create Tree in angular 4 with custom JSON

Tags: angular

I need to create Tree, but I have custom JSON like below

```
[
  {
    "Id": "29",
    "ParentId": "-1",
    "TITLE_AR": "xxxx",
    "TITLE_EN": "xxxx",
    "Level": "1",
    "Hirarchy": "/29",
    "IsActive": true,
    "IsParent": true,
    "isLeaf": false,
    "IsClickable": true,
    "SearchFlag": "0"
  },
  {
    "Id": "30",
    "ParentId": "29",
    "TITLE_AR": "yyyyyy",
    "TITLE_EN": "yyyyyy",
    "Level": "2",
    "Hirarchy": "/29/30",
    "IsActive": true,
    "IsParent": true,
    "isLeaf": false,
    "IsClickable": true,
    "SearchFlag": "0"
  },
  {
    "Id": "31",
    "ParentId": "30",
    "TITLE_AR": "rrrrrr",
    "TITLE_EN": "rrrrrr",
    "Level": "3",
    "Hirarchy": "/29/30/31",
    "IsActive": true,
    "IsParent": false,
    "isLeaf": true,
    "IsClickable": true,
    "SearchFlag": "0"
  },
  {
    "Id": "32",
    "ParentId": "29",
    "TITLE_AR": "cccccccc",
    "TITLE_EN": "cccccccc",
    "Level": "2",
    "Hirarchy": "/29/32",
    "IsActive": true,
    "IsParent": false,
    "isLeaf": true,
    "IsClickable": true,
    "SearchFlag": "0"
  },
  {
    "Id": "35",
    "ParentId": "29",
    "TITLE_AR": "88888888888888",
    "TITLE_EN": "888888888888888888",
    "Level": "2",
    "Hirarchy": "/29/35",
    "IsActive": true,
    "IsParent": false,
    "isLeaf": true,
    "IsClickable": true,
    "SearchFlag": "0"
  }
]
```

How I can create the tree like the image below

[image]

I searched a lot on the internet but to no avail,

More than one reference has been tried like

1 - https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/angular-material-tree/

2 - https://www.infragistics.com/products/ignite-ui-angular/angular/components/tree

3 - https://www.lidorsystems.com/help/integralui/web-components/treeview/drag-drop-between-treeviews/

Comment: You should look into this here https://material.angular.io/components/tree/overview

Answer (score 0):

At first, you have to transform your JSON to something more friendly to use, something like this:

[image: Parsed JSON]

You can achieve that with this code:

```
json_data = getChildren(json_data, 1);

function getChildren(elements, level) {
   elements.forEach(item => {
      item["children"] = json_data.filter(i => i.ParentId === item.Id);
      getChildren(item["children"], (level + 1));
   })

   elements = elements.filter(item => Number(item.Level) === level);

   return elements;
}
```

Where `json_data` is the JSON you posted.

Now is pretty easy to generate the structure:

```
<div class="tree" *ngFor="let node1 of json_data">
   <div class="sub-node-1" *ngFor="let node2 of node1.children">
      <div class="sub-node-2" *ngFor="let node3 of node2.children">
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```